# How to disable 5.2 feature or emails - "is a built-in feature that detects when a plugin or theme causes a fatal error"

Tags: wordpress

New built-in feature is sending my clients into a tizzy. They are "alarmed" to receive these emails. So far, their websites are fine, and the emails generated by this are "sensational" but have no real content value... just a message - look at the website.

Is there a plugin to disable this or a way to do it in the config file?  A way to have the emails sent to me other than "admin" on general settings?  How are you getting around this?

Comment: Their websites aren't "fine" if they're getting these messages. Hiding the problem isn't the best way to go about it. Fix whatever is causing the issue(s) instead and these "sensational" email messages will be gone.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The issue is: I don't want THEM to get those emails because they don't understand. I don't need panic when I can fix something quickly.
If you have information that can help me with that, instead of passing judgement on my intentions, I would appreciate hearing your information.

Comment: Apologies, I was a bit rash on my previous comment. Yesterday was a stressful day. And to answer your question, actually I do know. Please check the answer below.

Comment: Wonderful!  THank you Hector. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [recovery_mode_email filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/recovery_mode_email/) to customize the email that's sent when an unrecoverable error happens, including of course the email address it is sent to:

```
/**
  * Modify the recovery mode email address.
  *
  * @param array $email_data
  * @return  array $email_data
  */
function wp_87524_customize_recovery_mode_email($email_data) {
    $email_data['to'] = 'user@example.com';
    return $email_data;
}
add_filter('recovery_mode_email', 'wp_87524_customize_recovery_mode_email');
```

Add that code to either your theme's `functions.php` file or to a standalone plugin and you're good to go.